# ubuntu CRON: (root)) CMD ( cd / && run-parts -- report /etc/cron.hourly) when installing ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, cron

so I was trying to completely install ubuntu and remove Windows 10 on my computer but when i tried selecting the option on the installer that would remove all OS on the computer, it says something like this:
"The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI2 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed. You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu." 
I clicked continue and it seemed like it was installing but then after hours the bar was not moving at all. I clicked on the details and it said:
"[date] [time] ubuntu CRON[numbers]: (root)) CMD ( cd / && run-parts -- report /etc/cron.hourly)"

When I tried to boot my computer it wasn't working. No windows 10 nor ubuntu that was installed. What do I do now? Please help.